# Proving $|a| + |b| \leq |a+b| + |a-b|$ using the Triangle Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, triangle-inequality

> Prove
> $$|a| + |b| \leq |a+b| + |a-b|$$
> using the Triangle Inequality.

Struggling a bit with this question, here's the little progress I made.

$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

$|a-b| \leq |a| + |b|$

$|a+b| + |a-b| \leq 2|a|$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$|a| = \left|\dfrac{a+b}{2} + \dfrac{a-b}{2}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}(|a+b| + |a-b|)$$
and you can do a similar thing for $|b|$ to obtain your claim.